# git push heroku master fails with SSH Key Fingerprint

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, git-push

When I want to **git push heroku master** it says

```
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.
 !  
 !  SSH Key Fingerprint: [fingerprint things here]

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How do I fix this? [Screenshot with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lTbW.png)
I tried a lot but nothing helped
(*sorry if my english is bad, im from germany*)

Comment: The problem is not with "*SSH Key Fingerprint*" but with  "*Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git*" Start debugging with `git remote -v`

Comment: I debugged it now. What is next? Here is a Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/rFgIRAi

Comment: Push. If it's pushed without an error — everything is ok, you app is running.

Comment: It is still not working.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: Same Error: https://imgur.com/a/WxPRAft

Comment: But I found another way to host my Bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I`m running my bot on UptimeRobot with Glitch**